# Entity Framework: Dependencies due to foreign key constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have been looking around for a solution and cannot find good information. A lot of EF documentation is very out of date. Here is my problem.

If I add a child to a parent via the ParentID navigation property, everything works fine.

If I add a child to a parent via the Children list and the child is pre-existing, I get this exception:

> DbUpdateException: Unable to determine
>   a valid ordering for dependent
>   operations. Dependencies may exist due
>   to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated
>   values.

If I add a child to a parent via the Children list and the child is new (also needs to be persisted), I get this exception:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store
>   update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows
>   (0). Entities may have been modified
>   or deleted since entities were loaded.
>   Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Node.cs

```
public class Node
{
  public long ID { get; private set; }
  public long? ParentID { get; set; }
  public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Relevant DbContext.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
  mb.Entity<Node>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Children)
    .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your Children property

`public virtual ICollection<Node>` instead of a `List<Node>`

Comment: I don't want dynamic proxies. I will try marking with virtual and turning proxies off, but I don't think that will help. This is not a lazy-loading issue or anything (as far as I know I suppose). I will have to update tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, not sure what is the best solution but i tried to call SaveChanges. context.SaveChanges() and then Add the Child to Newly Created Entity and it worked.